# Memcache-based message queue?

Tags: memcached, message-queue

I'm working on a multiplayer game and it needs a message queue (i.e., messages in, messages out, no duplicates or deleted messages assuming there are no unexpected cache evictions). Here are the memcache-based queues I'm aware of:

- MemcacheQ: http://memcachedb.org/memcacheq/
- Starling: http://rubyforge.org/projects/starling/
- Depcached: http://www.marcworrell.com/article-2287-en.html
- Sparrow: http://code.google.com/p/sparrow/

I learned the concept of the memcache queue from [this blog post](http://broddlit.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/memcached-as-simple-message-queue/):

*All messages are saved with an integer as key. There is one key that has the next key and one that has the key of the oldest message in the queue. To access these the increment/decrement method is used as its atomic, so there are two keys that act as locks. They get incremented, and if the return value is 1 the process has the lock, otherwise it keeps incrementing. Once the process is finished it sets the value back to 0. Simple but effective. One caveat is that the integer will overflow, so there is some logic in place that sets the used keys to 1 once we are close to that limit. As the increment operation is atomic, the lock is only needed if two or more memcaches are used (for redundancy), to keep those in sync.*

My question is, is there a memcache-based message queue service that can run on App Engine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would be very careful using the Google App Engine Memcache in this way.  You are right to be worrying about "unexpected cache evictions".

Google expect you to use the memcache for *caching* data and not *storing* it.  They don't guarantee to keep data in the cache.  From the [GAE Documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions.html):

> By default, items never expire, though
>   items may be evicted due to memory
>   pressure.

**Edit:** There's always [Amazon's Simple Queueing Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).  However, this may not meet price/performance levels either as:

1. There would be the latency of calling from the Google to Amazon servers.
2. You'd end up paying twice for all the data traffic - paying for it to leave Google and then paying again for it to go in to Amazon.

Comment: I would expect that expiry of items in the cache will be based on inactivity so if the queue lifetimes are as you say then you'd probably be fine.  Although there are a lot of qualifiers in that statement so you'd definitely need to handle lost items in the queue.

Comment: I also need to use a message queue with GAE, but I do not have idea on how to connect the above mentioned memcache based queue services (MemcacheQ, sparrow etc.) with GAE, as GAE only supports Java and Python, so I would like to know any idea on it. Also what are the other message queue services we can use with GAE, other than AmazonSQS?

Answer (score 4):

I have started a Simple Python Memcached Queue, it might be useful:
http://bitbucket.org/epoz/python-memcache-queue/

Comment: I seem to remember seeing this technique before, but +1 for packaging like this.

Comment: I trying to do something like this here:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/SimpleMessageQueue
however, without locking, there is slightly possible to lose messages.
from the other side, if lock never expires, whole operation may get stuck.
if you do lock expiration, then a mess can happen if you are releasing the lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the possibility of losing data, by all means go ahead. Bear in mind, though, that although memcache generally has lower latency than the datastore, like anything else, it will suffer if you have a high rate of atomic operations you want to execute on a single element. This isn't a datastore problem - it's simply a problem of having to serialize access.

Failing that, Amazon's SQS seems like a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Task Queue:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/ 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/

It seems to solve the issue without the likely loss of messages in Memcached-based queue.

Answer (score 0):

Until Google impliment a proper job-queue, why not use the data-store? As others have said, memcache is just a cache and could lose queue items (which would be.. bad)

The data-store should be more than fast enough for what you need - you would just have a simple Job model, which would be more flexible than memcache as you're not limited to key/value pairs

Comment: Especially with the recent performance problems, it's not going to be cost effective. Under heavy usage I'm expecting to put > 1 million messages per day through this queue. It would be cheaper to use Amazon queue service than the datastore.