# Consuming tasks from GAE Task Queue

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I would like to use `Task Queue` with my App in `GAE`. As I know (according to `Task Queue` documentation and API), we can add tasks to `push queue`, and then they are being consumed automatically by the app. Also in `pull queue`, we can add tasks, and tasks are being consumed automatically according to scaling properties we handle.

I would like to know whether there is ability to consume tasks from `task queue` (`push or pull queues`), when we want by calling a `consume-like method`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how push and pull task queues works. In both queues you add tasks to the queue, but while in push queue the system will dequeue the task and assign it to the apropriate handler in pull queue you need to dequeue the task(s) using lease_tasks and handle the task.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Also I would like to know whether it is ok to use Task Queue (pull queue) as a message queue to GAE (Since GAE does not provide a message queue for it). Also if it is not, what is the best option to use as a message queue to GAE? I also referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625146/memcache-based-message-queue-for-app-engine, but according to what I know, it is not possible to connect these memcache based message queues (MemcacheQ, sparrow etc.) to GAE as GAE supports only Java and Python.

Comment: Why would it not be okay? And what precisely is the difference between a message queue and a task queue?

Comment: @NickJohnson: As far as I know, the Task queue is also a message oriented middle-ware though not full fledged. I also referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075817/message-queue-vs-task-queue-difference and your comment there too, and according to all that I have read so far, I think it is ok to use pull queue as a message queue... Thanks

Comment: What does it actually mean for something to be "middle-ware though not full fledged"?

Comment: As I read, it seems Task queue is not a full-fledged message oriented middleware. Please I would like to have any clarification regarding this, since I have not used it before. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that the tasks added to a pull queue are not automatically consumed.

The consume-like method you want is [lease_tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull#Leasing_Tasks) (note this is for pull queues only). If you want to consume the tasks at a given time you can have an endpoint that processes these tasks. Also you can set [cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) to call that particular endpoint.